# Get the first ocurrence of a string in a variable REGEX

Tags: regex

I have the following variable in a database: `PSC-CAMPO-GRANDE-I08-V00-C09-H09-IPRMKT` and I want to split it into two variables, the first will be `PSC-CAMPO-GRANDE-I08` and the second `V00-C09-H09-IPRMKT`.

I'm trying the regex `.*(\-I).*(\-V)`, this doesn't work. Then I tried `.*(\-I)`, but it gets the last `-IPRMKT` string.

Then my question is: There a way of split the string `PSC-CAMPO-GRANDE-I08-V00-C09-H09-IPRMKT` considering the first occurrence of `-I`?

Comment: What is the environment? Try [`(.*?-I[^-]*)-(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/bQ7mdX/2). If you are using a POSIX regex engine, it won't work.

Comment: What is wrong with [**`^([^I]+)-[^-]+-(.+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/L64sWt/2/) ?

Comment: @Jan: And if there is `PSC-RIO-GRANDE-I08`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It won't work then, of course :)

Comment: Thanks, guys! It works!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
regex = "(.*?-I[\d]{2})-(.*)"
```

Here is test script in Python

```
import re

regex = "(.*?-I[\d]{2})-(.*)"

match = re.search(regex, "PSC-CAMPO-GRANDE-I08-V00-C09-H09-IPRMKT")
if match:
    print ("yep")
    print (match.group(1))
    print (match.group(2))
else:
    print ("nope")
```

In the regex, I'm grabbing everything up to the first -I then 2 numbers.  Then match but don't capture a -.  Then capture the rest.  I can help tweak it if you have more logic that you are trying to do.

Comment: @Lucas-Bicalho if this helped you please accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(.*?-I[^-]*)-(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ7mdX/3)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.*?-I[^-]*)` - Group 1:

  - `.*?` - any 0+ 0+ chars other than line break chars up to the *first* (*because `*?` is a lazy quantifier that matches up to the first occurrence*)
  - `-I` - a literal substring `-I`
  - `[^-]*` - any 0+ chars other than a hyphen (*your pattern was missing it*)
- `-` -  a hyphen
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars up to the end of a line.